# Docker Container localhost "isn’t working right now"

Tags: docker, docker-compose, jupyter-notebook, dockerfile, jupyter

I have a jupyter notebook docker container that is running on localhost 8888. I installed some custom Python packages to this container and committed this container by `docker commit image_id image_name:tag`

`docker images` also show the new image.

After that, `docker run -it -d --name container_name-p 8080:8080 image_name:tag`
with this command, I am trying to create a new container on localhost 8080. But it is showing **"This page isn’t working right now"**.

I  also checked by `docker exec --user root -it container_id /bin/bash`  the container is working perfectly via the terminal.

Do you have any suggestions or am I missing anything? Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: If you did not change at which port jupter notebook is running, then it's still on 8888. So ports should be 8080:8888

Comment: Do you have a [mcve]?  "I installed some stuff and ran `docker commit`" is extremely hard to reproduce, to the point where I'd suggest `docker commit` is almost never a best practice.  A better approach would be to write a custom Dockerfile that installed the packages you need; you could include that as part of the required source code in your question, and anyone could recreate the image.